# QDialog deletes its QLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qt4

I have a Qt4 application, that has numerous dialogs. I am curious to know whether or not a QDialog deletes its Layout. Take for example:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog {
  public:
    MyDialog(QWidget* _parent = 0) : QDialog(_parent) {
      //instantiate some widgets
      m_layout = new QGridLayout(this);
      setLayout(m_layout)
      //add some widgets to the layout
    }

    ~MyDialog() {
      //Do I need this code? or will the parent delete the layout?
      //delete m_layout;
    }
 private:
   QGridLayout* m_layout;
}
```

So do I need to write my own destructor? or will the QDialog take care of the memory management of *m_layout*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QDialog` will delete the `QLayout` upon destruction.  You do not need to delete the layout in the destructor.

See also: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setLayout

Comment: Maybe a little extension to say that is a behaviour that is available with all descendants of QObject [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)